# React Redux | connect not mapping dispatch to props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to react and I am making a little business directory as I'm learning.

I've made a very basic component such as:

BusinessDirectory.js

```
export class BusinessDirectory extends React.Component {

   componentWillMount() {
       console.log(this.props);
   }

    render() {
       return (<div><h1>Business Directory</h1></div>) 
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  businesses: state.businesses.items
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchBusinesses })(BusinessDirectory);
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import { BusinessDirectory } from "./components/BusinessDirectory";

import store from "./store";

export class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BusinessDirectory />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  applyMiddleware(...middleware)
);

export default store;
```

reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import businessReducer from "./business.reducer";

export default combineReducers({
  businesses: businessReducer
});
```

reducers/business.reducer.js

```
import { FETCH_BUSINESS, FETCH_BUSINESSES } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  items: []
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_BUSINESSES:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: action.payload
      };
      break;
   default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

business.action.js

```
import { FETCH_BUSINESSES } from "./types";

export const fetchBusinesses = () => dispatch => {
  fetch("http://localhost:5000/businesses")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data =>
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_BUSINESSES,
        payload: data.data
      })
    );
};
```

The issue I am having is that `this.props` inside of the `BusinessDirectory` is an empty object so I cannot call the methods that I am creating. I've tried to do it by doing the `mapDispatchToProp` but that also doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that in App.js you import the wrong component:

```
import { BusinessDirectory } from "./components/BusinessDirectory";
```

will import the so called named export, i.e. what you defined as

```
export class BusinessDirectory extends React.Component {
```

This is a class that assumes that "someone" passes the props to it.

On the other hand,

```
import BusinessDirectory from "./components/BusinessDirectory";
```

would import the default export, which is the connected component

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchBusinesses })(BusinessDirectory);
```

i.e. a component that actually takes care of passing the props from redux.